# How does the JavaScript `debugger` keyword work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, ecmascript-6, ecma

I understand **what** `debugger`'s do in JavaScript.

What I don't understand is **how** they work?

It's almost like they somehow bubble an event caught by the debugging tool around it? **How** do they force Chrome for example to stop JS execution and take a snapshot of the callstack?

The [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.15) is a little vague around what exactly happens to `debugger` keywords

Comment: More than just being vague, the spec says "implementation defined", which basically means "do whatever you like". If you really want to, you can investigate the V8 source code to try to find how they've implemented the debugger statement https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git

Comment: You may want to start looking around https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/dc712da548c7fb433caed56af9a021d964952728/src/runtime/runtime-debug.cc#L137 and https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/dc712da548c7fb433caed56af9a021d964952728/src/debug/debug.cc#L2092

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, the magic in browsers is actually on the html side, in the event loop where a small algorithm called ["spin the event loop"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop) allows to make this happen. Because yep, brwsers aren't written in js and don't even need js to do most of their job.

Comment: The parsing and implementation of the `debugger` keyword is built into the JS engine itself where they have access to the stack and other JS state.  It is entirely implementation dependent exactly how they do it.  The only standard is that it will pause the JS execution and take you to the debugger to show you some current state (if a debugger is available) in the similar way that a breakpoint would.

Comment: It doesn't force anything. All it does is to instruct a debugger (**iff** open/attached), "please insert a breakpoint here". If you want to know how breakpoints and debuggers work, that's a very different question.

Comment: Thank you all for the context and explanation this is very useful